# how to associate onclick handler to check box came through ajax php

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i retrieve a table from ajax request and in that table i have a check box and i want to get its onClick function in jquery.please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing it:
One is as above using .live()
or you can bind the .click() event to the checkboxes after the ajax call, e.g.

```
$.post('url/path', function(response) {
  $('.checkboxes').click( function() {
    //do stuff here
  });
});
```

The .live() method is easy, but it has limitations namely the event bubbling limitations, where it refuses to propagate events normally.

Comment: it is still behaving strange when i click on the second check box it automatically either checks off  or checks on the other checkbox

Comment: i am doing the way you mentioned but the problem is with the first check box it always gets ticked or gets unticked when i tick any other check box down the tabel.

Comment: could you post an example of what you're doing? Or explain in more detail what it is you want to acheive?
Also please post the exact code that you tried above.

Comment: and upon reading amosrivera's answer, he is correct, delegate is probably the best option here, or doing something like
  $('.checkbox', $('#checkbox_container')[0]).live( function() { .. do stuff });
which is pretty much equivalent to delegate, but delegate is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function instead, the advantage is it reduces the weight of adding a `click`  handler to **every** checkbox and is not affected if new rows are created dynamically or not, instead it adds it to the whole table and when you click on it, then it finds out which checkbox you clicked, you only need to have an empty table for instance

```
<table id="my_table">
</table>
```

Then when you can append the new rows. And your click event code should look something like this:

```
$("#my_table").delegate('checkbox',function(){
    $(this)
       .closest("tr")
       .css({background:"red"}); //example purposes, not necessary
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event for this. Assign a class to the dynamically generated checkboxes and use the following code.

```
$("#yourtableid input:checkbox.checkboxclass").live("click", function(){
    // to get the parent row
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    // to prevent event bubbling
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Does this is the standard way for accessing all those fields comming through ajax ? if yes then thankx a lot you solved my problem. if there is more please add.

Comment: `.live()` will attach event handler to all dynamically generated elements.

Comment: can you please help me in thinking how can i associate the whole row of input fields comming through ajax with that check box so that when the check box is clicked using the .live() method it granbs the whole row??

Comment: Your updated code does not give error and it does not give any valid thing returned in var row ? and event bubbling is still not controllable